# Delete records from table in many to many relationship?

Tags: java, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am using hibernate many to many association. i have 3 tables(STUDENT,COURSE and STUDENT_COURSE). among 3 tables 2 are main tables and one table is intermediate table for providing relation ship. when record is deleted from STUDENT then corresponding mapping is deleted from STUDENT_COURSE. my requirement is it should even delete record from COURSE table.
consider STUDENT_COURSE entries as below:

```
S-Id  C_ID
101   201
102   202
```

when 101 is deleted form STUDENT table, first entry from above table is deleted but record corresponding to 201 in COURSE table stays as is. how can i delete that record? do i need to execute a delete query? does many to many relation ship does not take care?
Below is my configuration:

```
<set name="course" table="STUDENT_COURSE" 
            inverse="false" lazy="false" fetch="join" cascade="all" >
            <key>
                <column name="S_Id" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <many-to-many entity-name="COURSE">
                <column name="C_Id" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-many>
        </set>
```

Thanks!

Comment: how does the relationship look like on student side? Do you also have cascade="all" there?

Comment: @Korgen thanks for your reply. above configuration is of student hbm only.

Comment: sorry, I mean on course side...

Comment: course side i dont have anything set. my requirement is, even if course is deleted, student should not be deleted but if student is deleted then course should be deleted.

Comment: what do you mean with "course side i dont have anything set"... you don't have a hbm file for course? Does your object graph get loaded correctly (i.e. if you load a student its courses will be populated)?

Comment: I don't fully understand the need to delete the course. A course may have many students enrolled, so deleting the course as well does not seem the appropriate action. For instance, if I extend your example had (101,201), (102, 201) and (102, 202) records in the STUDENT_COURSE table, would you still want to delete the COURSE 201 record? What is the business logic driving your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to delete Corresponding Course also if I delete a Student, Ok Like you did the configuration in Student hbm on Student => STUDENT_COURSE mapping for `inverse and cascade` , the same you need to do in STUDENT_COURSE hbm also for STUDENT_COURSE => COURSE mapping.